# After AlertView, tint color of parent view remains grey

Tags: uiwebview, uicollectionview, uialertview, tintcolor

I have a parent view controller (CollectionView). When you tap on a cell, the app pushed a WebView. In the ViewDidLoad method, I check to see if an internet connection is available. If there is no internet connection, I display an AlertView that notifies the user about the lack of a network connection. When they dismiss the AlertView and then hit the back buttona and go back to the main view, the UISegmentedControler that was tinted is suddenly grey. If I tap on it, it returns to the correct tint color (one segment at a time). Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your app delegate:

```
window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```